# nginx ssl reverse proxy in docker not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, openssl

I want to create a proxy with docker-compose but I get this output:

curl https://localhost

`curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading`

and "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" in firefox

curl http://localhost

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

(Shows default page in chrome and firefox, but should actually return 301 > https)

---

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3-alpine
    restart: on-failure:3
    container_name: proxy

    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl/crt.crt:/root/ssl/crt.crt:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl/key.key:/root/ssl/key.key:ro

    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

nginx default file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name   _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name localhost;

  ssl_certificate /root/ssl/crt.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/key.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

in container:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root          1749 Feb 17 12:36 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root          1322 Feb 17 10:38 /root/ssl/crt.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1704 Feb 17 10:38 /root/ssl/key.key


/ # nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful


/ # netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:40079        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
```

Can someone tell me where my error is?

This config works in nginx which runs directly on the pc.

Comment: can you provide the output of nginx -t command inside your nginx container?

Comment: / # nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my mistake, the file "default" I have changed to "nginx.conf", now it works

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3-alpine
    restart: on-failure:3
    container_name: proxy

    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:ro # <-- that was the mistake
      - ./nginx/ssl/crt.crt:/root/ssl/crt.crt:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl/key.key:/root/ssl/key.key:ro

    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```